# Change html text using jquery (asp.net)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net web form with the bootstrap navbar. How can I access the HTML text of a navigation bar using Jquery and change the value before page load? i.e I want to change sign up to "username" before the page is displayed

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="signupnav" href="#" onclick="signUp()" >Sign up</a></li>
       <li><a class="signinnav" href="#" onclick="signIn()" >Sign in</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: You have mistakenly provided contradictory class names.

Comment: @Zeeshan Lol i dint see that

Comment: Np problem..check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `document`'s ready event will be fired before `window`'s load event.

So we can accomplish your task by,

```
$(function(){
  $("ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right").find("a.signupnav").text("username");

  // or a less readable version:
  // 1. $("ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right a.signupnav").text("username");
  // 2. $("ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right > a.signupnav").text("username");

  //Your other code below...
  //...
});
```

And this `$(function(){...});` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){...});`. So don't confuse with that.

Comment: @adarshjaya12 Are you seeing any errors in your console? Have you included Jquery library?

Comment: If username is a variable, you should use it without the quotes.

Comment: @adarshjaya12  Is `username` a variable? Define not working first of all. //good point.. Poul Bak.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy he is the link to the code im working http://pastebin.com/LiTSFVmJ

Comment: @adarshjaya12 `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` Insert this script tag before product.js's script tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it using following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('ul.nav .signupnav').text("Username");
});
```

Comment: `.signinnav` or `.signupnav`?

Comment: His class name where that way so i put siginnav...edited now